# iOS: Copying file from bundle on application start-up

Tags: ios, copy, bundle, nsfilemanager

When the user first uses my application,  it should copy a configuration file from the bundle into some folder.   The user can then fiddle with this file,  and if they mess it up they can simply press ' restore ' which will delete the file and copy it again from the bundle.

```
- (void) resetPresets
{
    LOG_( @"Copying tunings file from original..." );

    // copy default tunings -> curr tunings file

    NSString* appSupportDir = [NSFileManager appSupportDir];
    NSString* tuningsPath = [appSupportDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"tunings.txt"];

    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString* origTuningsPath = [bundle pathForResource: @"tuningsOriginal"
                                                 ofType: @"txt" ];


    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError* error = nil;

    if( [fileManager fileExistsAtPath: tuningsPath] )
    {
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath: tuningsPath
                                error: & error ];
        if( error ) 
            LOG( @"\n ERROR: %@ \n %@ \n", [error userInfo], [error localizedFailureReason] );
    }


    assert( [fileManager fileExistsAtPath: origTuningsPath] );

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath: origTuningsPath
                         toPath: tuningsPath
                          error: & error ];

    if( error ) 
        LOG( @"\n ERROR: %@ \n %@ \n", [error userInfo], [error localizedFailureReason] );


    LOG( @"done!" );


    // load profiles from it
    [self loadProfilesFromFile: tuningsPath ];

    // auto-sets active preset index to 0 & saves prefs
    self.activeThemeIndex = 0;
}
```

relies on a simple category:

```
#import "NSFileManager+addons.h"


@implementation NSFileManager ( NSFileManager_addons )

+ (NSString *) appSupportDir
{

    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                         NSApplicationSupportDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, 
                                                         YES
                                                         );

    NSString* appSupportDir = [paths objectAtIndex: 0];

    return appSupportDir;
}

@end
```

this is the line causing the problem:

```
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath: origTuningsPath
                         toPath: tuningsPath
                          error: & error ];
```

and this is the console output:

> [presets init]   Presets -> first run! Setting up with default
>   presets Copying tunings file from original...  ERROR: {
>       NSDestinationFilePath =
>   "/var/mobile/Applications/38FC3C65-74AF-4892-B48D-A3508A8CF404/Library/Application
>   Support/tunings.txt";
>       NSFilePath =
>   "/var/mobile/Applications/38FC3C65-74AF-4892-B48D-A3508A8CF404/Fork.app/tuningsOriginal.txt";
>       NSUserStringVariant = Copy; }   No such file or directory

Why is it complaining that there is no such file or directory?   Obviously there should not be such a file existing.   when you copy a file to a new location you don't expect a file to be there.

so I guess it is complaining about the directory.   But I have fished the directory out using a fairly standard method.   what is going on?   Is this not the right directory to be using?   Or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directories returned by `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` are not guaranteed to exist; you need to create them yourself, if necessary (see [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-SW5)). NSFileManager's [`createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW5) can help with that.